# Fill down starting when condition is met and until other condition in SAS

Tags: sas

I am stuck to solve this issue in SAS. It is probably not that complicated but I tried things with retain and do loops which didn't work.

Basically each ID has data on each date. Based on other variables they can enter in a state of decrease (variable step >0) and sometimes they will meet the final condition1. If condition1=1 is met I need to flag the "episode" starting at the begining of the decrease.

Below is an example of what my data looks like and column flag is what I need. I have put the data in ascending order for us to understand

```
    ID  date    step    condition1  flag
    z   1       0       .   
    z   2       0       .   
    z   3       0       .   
    z   4       1       .           TRUE
    z   5       2       .           TRUE
    z   6       2       .           TRUE
    z   7       3       .           TRUE
    z   8       4       .           TRUE
    z   10      4       .           TRUE
    z   11      4       1           TRUE
    z   12      4       .   
    z   13      4       .   
    z   14      0       .   
    z   15      0       .   
    z   16      0       .   
    z   17      1       .   
    z   18      2       .   
    z   19      2       .   
    z   20      0       .   
    z   21      0       .
```

edit: table with the variable used to determine decrease

```
ID  date    quantity    step    condition1  flag
z   1       90          0       .   
z   2       90          0       .   
z   3       100         0       .   
z   4       90          1       .           TRUE
z   5       80          2       .           TRUE
z   6       80          2       .           TRUE
z   7       50          3       .           TRUE
z   8       0           4       .           TRUE
z   10      0           4       .           TRUE
z   11      0           4       1           TRUE
z   12      0           4       .   
z   13      0           4       .   
z   14      40          0       .   
z   15      50          0       .   
z   16      60          0       .   
z   17      40          1       .   
z   18      40          2       .   
z   19      30          2       .   
z   20      60          0       .   
z   21      60          0       .
```

I've tried to sort it by ID and descending date, which seems to make sense.

```
proc sort data= have; 
by id descending  date ;
run;
```

Here is one of the many things I tried - but it gets stuck; (Edited)

```
DATA want  ;
SET have;
if four=1 then do;
 do until (step<1) ; flag=1;  output;
 end;
end;
run;
```

Any help appreciated. I probably just need a hint in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Do you know when the beginning of the decrease has started? Is there a set of variables both before and after that can be used to identify if this is the start of a decrease? If so, I may have a solution for you. Can you update your example data with the variable of interest that is measuring a decrease?

Comment: I have added a column where decrease is measured. But I am not sure it brings anything more than the variable step itself. Only step=1 would delimit the start of the decrease. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within group processing requiring an evaluation over a set of rows, which has to be applied to the same rows, can be done using a 'serial DOW' coding pattern.  Your data might have multiple segments within a group, so the whole thing would be nested in an outer do loop.

Example

Your step and condition combinations constraints are not fully explained, so the example logic might not cover all cases.

In this example `index_first_after_last_zero` tracks the start of a run of rows with `step > 0` and ending with `condition1 = 1`

```
data want;
  do until (last.id);

    segment = sum(segment,1);  * <------ helper for understanding logic;

    * 'measuring loop' that computes or tracks some multi-row condition within group;
    do index = 1 by 1 until (condition1 or last.id);
      set have;       * <------ SET inside loop;
      by id date;     * <------ BY for last.id and ensures dates are ordered;

      * track start of last run of non-zero steps;
      if step=0 then 
        index_first_after_last_zero = index + 1;
    end;

    * track end of run flag;
    segment_end_condition = condition1;

    * end of loop value is fixed at start of loop and thus not affected by automatic BY 1 increment;
    * thus 1 to index iterates same number of rows as the 'measuring' loop;
    do index = 1 to index;

      set have;     * <------ second SET use a separate file buffer than first SET;

      * apply flag value -- missing for pre-run rows, and end of run flag to run rows;
      if index < index_first_after_last_zero 
        then flag = .;
        else flag = segment_end_condition;

      OUTPUT;
    end;

  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, I don't think I would have been able to come up with this. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `do until` like that in a data step - it will iterate around, but it won't read any additional observations from the input data set.

I think the key idea you need is to maintain separate state variable(s) to remember what you've seen already:

```
proc sort data=have; 
  by id date;
run;

data want;
  retain episode_started episode_finished;
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id then do;
    episode_started = 0;
    episode_finished = 0;
  end;
  if step > 0 then episode_started = 1;
  if episode_started and not episode_finished then flag = 'TRUE';
  output;
  if condition1 then episode_finished = 1;
run;
```

I haven't tested this but it should be close. You can review the two added flags in the output data set to understand when and how they're being set. You could achieve the same thing by using a single state variable with more than two values, but the code above is clearer, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the issue is that if there is a decrease but the condition1 is not met at the end, this code would still flag it. maybe it could work with upside down data (sorted by descending date)?